# Microsoft Sql server schedule jobs - history being deleted

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've got several Scheduled jobs in Microsoft SQL server.  I would like the history on these jobs to last indefinitely or at least a few months.

I see that by right clicking on "SQL Server agent" and going to properties, I can set the maximum number of lines to keep, but it’s currently set to 1000 and I’m well under that limit.  I can also set the amount of time to keep records but it’s currently unchecked.

Any thoughts on what else could be deleting my records?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any maintenance plans running on the server. If so, one of them might contain an agent history cleanup task or be calling sp_purge_jobhistory .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186524(v=SQL.105).aspx